# UICollectionView background image not stretching on rotation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm working on getting my UICollectionView to rotate correctly.  In viewDidLoad I have:

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shelvesipad.png"]];
```

When in portrait mode, it works fine, but when I rotate (as the image is sized for portrait) instead of stretching out, it simply repeats.  How can I get this to stretch instead of basically tiling?

Answer (score 2):

The reason the picture is repeating is because you used colorWithPatternImage:. Try setting the collectionView image to your image.